# Error in .local(object, ...) when try to write or plot raster

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a randomForest model that I am trying to predict back over the study area. I am able to run the predict without errors, and I can see that it produces a raster, but when I try to run `writeRaster()` or `plot()`, I get the error `Error in .local(.object, ...)` without any more information. Here is the code (note that envStack is the raster stack of environmental predictors and rf.full is the randomForest model object):

```
library(here)
library(raster)
library(randomForest)
setwd(here("species", model_species, "outputs", "grids"))
fn <- paste0(model_run_name, "_raw_", Sys.Date(), ".tif")

outRas <- predict(object = envStack,
                  model = rf.full,
                  type = "prob",
                  index = 2, 
                  na.rm = TRUE,
                  filename = fn,
                  format = "GTiff",
                  overwrite = TRUE,
                  progress = "text")
writeRaster(outRas, filename = fn, format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

And, here is the error:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

The same thing happens if I try to plot the output raster:

```
plot(outRas)
```

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

I'm including a screenshot of the envStack and rf.full objects as well as the outRas raster product from the predict. To check if the issue was a file size issue, I used `object.size(outRas)`, which returned `12832 bytes`. I also checked the available space on the drive where I want to store the raster, and there are over 60 GB of free space:
[image: screenshot of raster stack, rf model, and output prediction raster objects]

I'm not sure why the min and max values are unknown for a lot of the rasters in the stack, but just to make sure the individual rasters weren't corrupt, I tried to plot one with missing min/max values (`plot(envStack[[1]])`), and it plotted just fine:
[image: plot of first raster in envStack]

The model object (`rf.full`) was used successfully to compute various validation metrics, so as far as I know, there are no issues with it, and the folder where I want to save the output raster exists.

[image]

When I check the temporary file location with `rasterTmpFile()`, it returns a file that doesn't exist (although the containing folder does):

```
rasterTmpFile()
[1] "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkxfn1t/raster/r_tmp_2020-02-17_152958_23480_67648.grd"
```

[image: empty temp folder]

I feel like I have encountered this issue before, but I can't remember how I resolved it (or if I resolved it). The related questions I have looked at on here point to file size and file location issues, which don't seem to by me problem. Some hint at issues with format type, but I have saved other rasters as GeoTiffs as recently as last week in earlier steps of this process using `writeRaster()` with `format = "GTiff"`. Also, the fact that I get the same error when just trying to plot `outRas` within R makes it seem like there is an issue with the raster itself. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE: The problem turned out to be that the `writeRaster()` statement was unnecessary. Taking it out solved the issue. See my answer below for more details.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had that code bit embedded in an if/else try statement, so it was trying to run the predict and write the raster as part of the same run. However, the `writeRaster()` line is unnecessary since the `predict()` function includes a `filename=` argument to save the file. By telling it to write the raster right after that confused R somehow and caused it to throw that error. Thus, I removed the `writeRaster()` statement, and it solved the problem.